# WordPress custom post type slug duplicate is crawled by search engine bots

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, search-engine, slug

I have a WordPress installation with multiple custom post types. They are working fine - slugs / rewrite rules and stuff like this works for the user. But now there is a problem with search engine bots. On some of the post types they try to crawl wrong URLs - e.g. for a post type called "Makler" - and therefore get 404 errors.

- This is the real and working URL which is crawled - `/makler/name`
- This is what search engines try to reach additionally - `/makler/makler/name`.

I checked the sitemaps and can't find where I am wrong. I noticed that this problem only occurs with custom post type that have the option "with_front" set on "false". So I think there is an issue with the rewrite rules.

I think it would be possible to fix this via `.htaccess` rules, but a workaround is not what I am looking for. Here is the URL - https://remaxmagdeburg.de/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  `https://remaxmagdeburg.de/makler/name` gives me a 404 error.

Comment: /name is just a placeholder - try this: https://remaxmagdeburg.de/makler/stefan-korn/ - but I checked it again. When im trying to reach /makler/makler/stefan-korn/ then I am redirected to the right page. This is weird - I have a plugin which is monitoring all 404 errors and this shows me that there is an error and no redirect.